# Why Windows doesn't delete the hiberfil file after restoring it's content into the RAM?

Tags: windows, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

Why don't Windows engineers allow the system to just delete and restore allocated space taken by hiberfil file?

Comment: Because you don't want to wait when reallocating the space takes time or space is used up by other apps / data?

Comment: I think that we agree that a system partition shouldn't have less 10gb or 15gb of free space which is sufficient to give for hibernation. I think the problem is (like @grawity mentioned down) the contiguity of the allocation, the more percentage you use of the drive the less the system is able to find a large contiguous free space.

Comment: Who says that 15 GB of free space is sufficient for hibernation?  I wouldn't expect that to be enough for a 16 GB system (much less my multi-year-old 24 GB system, or the 32-64 GB that are likely to be in my next system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This of course can only be answered by Windows engineers. But:

1. If you remove the hibernation file after resume, you have to allocate the space *again* every time immediately before hibernation.
2. If the disk doesn't have enough space, the OS cannot hibernate. More importantly, the hibernation file must be a *single contiguous chunk* of disk space – for example, if you have 30 GB free but it's five chunks × 6 GB, then it's impossible to create a 8 GB hiberfile.
3. If the OS cannot hibernate when the user asks it to, naturally the user will complain that the feature is broken and useless (because it is!). And if hibernation was automatic due to low battery, the OS will be forced to shut down (possibly losing unsaved documents) – or even just sit there until the battery runs out – making it appear broken too.

So the cost of permanently reserving the hiberfile (considering that it's a very small percentage of total disk space) is smaller than the cost of trying to do it every time with high risk of failure.

Answer (score 6):

Oh, I think you can do that, manually.  But it might not make sense to.  Which is probably why Windows doesn't do that by default.

What happens the next time you hibernate?  You'll just need to have that space allocated to hibernating then.

Usually when people want to hibernate, they want that to just work well, immediately.  When people try to start a hibernate, people often don't have time to want to fuss with freeing up disk space by deleting something else, in order to make room for the hibernating.

So if hibernating worked once, clearly the computer supports that functionality.  As much as features like Cortana may be highly publicized features, the ability to interact with the system's firmware in order to perform a basic task is probably ranked as a critical ability, so the operating system designers don't want to lose the ability to have that happen again.

If the space continues to be used up, then the user won't see that as available free space to fill, and thereby use up that free space and end up causing problems the next time the user wishes to hibernate.

Also, if people hibernate once relatively early in the computer's life cycle, hopefully there wasn't as much need for fragmentation.  If the same sectors are reserved in the future, the hibernating process may be less prone to need to use fragmented free space in order to accomplish the task.

Finally, deleting data takes a bit of resources (including time, and interacting with the disk which is a resource shared by different programs).  The amount of resources used up may be quite small, but small is more than none.  Why use up the resources when you don't need to?

So, to summarize, the answer to "what is stopping Windows" from doing this may be a counter-question of "why would Windows want to do this?"